# Python: money variable is not updating after coin toss. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to programming and part of my Python class assignment is to create random chance games.  First game is suppose to be "Coin Flip" and there is a money variable involved.  I got the coin flip function to work but for some reason it's not updating the money variable outside of the function. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
  import random

    money = 100

    #Write your game of chance functions here
    def coinflip(bet, choice):
      print("Your bet is " + str(bet))
      print("And your choice is "+ choice)
      new_money = 0
      if choice == "Heads":
        choice = 1
      elif choice == "Tails":
        choice = 2
      result = random.randint(1, 2)
      print(result)
      if choice == result:
        print("You have won!")
        money == money + bet * 2
        print(money)
        return money
      else:
        print("You have lost!")
        money == money - bet
        print(money)
        return money

    #Call your game of chance functions here
    coinflip(10, "Heads")
    print(money)
```

Thank You!

Comment: Side note: Your `new_money` never gets used :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function you need to declare that money is **global** like this:

```
def coinflip(bet, choice):
    global money
    ...
```

Also, you are not assigning new value, instead comparing two values. Use = instead of == in places like this one:

```
money == money + bet * 2
and
money == money - bet
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
money == money - bet
```

This *compares* `money` and `money - bet`, and then throws away the result of the comparison.

You meant `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what i have written.

Comment: Yes, but you hadn't yet while I was typing it. Doesn't matter.